# Nuget assembly not inside a framework folder

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am using **NuGetPackageExplorer** to publish a nuGet package on our private nuget feed. Before publishing I used menu option Tools->Analyze Package and getting a warning "`Assembly not inside a framework folder`".

> (Note: I also got an error related to lib folder earlier but corrected it by adding lib folder as suggested by NuGetPackageExplorer)

Following is my nuGet package structure:

```
->lib
     MyDll.Dll
```

I have not mentioned any specific framework in the Package Metadata.
(I also tried [NuGet Assembly outside lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855428/nuget-assembly-outside-lib-folder), but it is talking about "lib" folder)

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do this.

In NuGetPackageExplorer, point to Package Contents -> "lib" folder, if you right click on it (lib folder) then a menu appears and that menu has option to add Framework folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the [source-code of nuget](https://github.com/mono/nuget), you will find that this error can be ignored if your dll is targeted for multi-frameworks.

One unit [test for nuget core](https://github.com/mono/nuget/blob/d129831d6fa1c7e3c83b520b877a273c636e120e/test/Core.Test/Analysis/MisplacedAssemblyRuleTest.cs) seems to prove this.

Comment: Then you will have to put it in the framework specific folder which you have already done as mentioned in your own solution.